# Swift ios how to set nav bar image not stretch

Tags: ios, swift, navbar

I have made it possible to add a background image to a nav bar using the ff code but the image is stretched. Is there any way that it will not be stretched?

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "BG.jpg"), for: .default)
```

Comment: what would you like to do? setting background image or titleview? as @Jatin's answer will help you to set titleview

Comment: setting background image

Comment: Can you please share the resolution for navigation bar image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this,

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "BG.jpg")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
```

Try out other options in the code as well.

**UPDATE**

You can even try below category for `UINavigationBar`

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func setBackgroundImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.insertSubview(imageView, belowSubview: navigationBar)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

Above code may be vary depending on your final requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
class TutorialViewController: UIViewController {

// This property will set the Image to Navigation Bar
public var navigationBarImage: UIImage? {
    get {
        return (navigationItem.titleView as? UIImageView)?.image
    } set {
        if newValue != nil {
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: newValue)
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            navigationItem.titleView = imageView
        } else {
            navigationItem.titleView = nil
        }
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationBarImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "my_nav_image")
}
```

Comment: you can use like this `navigationBarImage = UIImage.init(named: "your image name")`

Answer (score 0):

for all images you can set the content mode =

```
.scaleToFill (UIViewContentModeScaleToFill)
.scaleAspectFit (UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit)
.scaleAspectFill (UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill)
```

If you do not want to see the contents that are outside the bounds you need to remember to set clipsToBounds to true on the containing superview

```
View.clipsToBounds = true
```